# PHP sets new value with if statment in foreach (Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using laravel if that could be the issue (I'm in the controller)
So I have this code.

If my $pool->status is etc OFFLINE it sets it to ONLINE.
why is this happening?

```
foreach($pools as $pool){
        if ($pool->status = 'ONLINE') {
            $pool->cstatus = '
            <i class="zmdi zmdi-shield-check zmdi-hc-lg text-success" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="" data-original-title="OK"></i>
            ';
        }
        else {
            $pool->cstatus = '
            <i class="zmdi zmdi-help zmdi-hc-lg text-muted" data-placement="right" title="" data-original-title="Status unknown."></i>
            ';
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

There is difference in "=" and "==" operators. = is **assingment** operator while == is **comparison** operator.

Change

```
  if ($pool->status = 'ONLINE') {
```

To

```
 if ($pool->status == 'ONLINE') {
```

Answer (score 1):

You used assignemnt operator `=`, not a [comparsion operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php).

So:

```
if ($pool->status == 'ONLINE') {}
```

Not:

```
if ($pool->status = 'ONLINE') {}
```

You can go with yoda condition:

```
if ('ONLINE' == $pool->status) {}
```

Because that would throw an error when you mistake operators.

These mistakes are hard to debug, especially for not experienced programmers.

Comment: Thanks, also great with the link!

Answer (score 0):

You are using assignment operator in your if statement, instead of conditional equals operator. It is the different between using `=` and `==`

```
foreach($pools as $pool){
        if ($pool->status == 'ONLINE') {
            $pool->cstatus = '
            <i class="zmdi zmdi-shield-check zmdi-hc-lg text-success" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="" data-original-title="OK"></i>
            ';
        }
        else {
            $pool->cstatus = '
            <i class="zmdi zmdi-help zmdi-hc-lg text-muted" data-placement="right" title="" data-original-title="Status unknown."></i>
            ';
        }
    }
```